# Modify TD elements Jquery

Tags: jquery

Folks, I need to dynamically add/remove icon using Jquery programatically      into `td`. The `td` looks as follows

```
<td>
  <input type="text" id="target_edit_WEB" class="selectized" style="width:100px; height:25px;" placeholder="Enter ResourceB"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:#D70F0F"></i> 
</td>
```

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: `$('td .fa').hide()` will hide `$('td .fa').show()` will show. You could also use .remove() and append() depending on what you want to archieve. Where do you have your problem?

Comment: The total TD tag string is contained in a variable "cell", please advise me syntax for the suggested solution

Comment: you need to be more clear of your criteria. when should it show? when should it hide? where is *total*, *cell*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
var $td = $('td:first');
var $icon = $td.find('i.fa:first');

if (!$icon.length) {
    $icon = $('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:#D70F0F">');
}

// remove icon
$icon.remove();

// add icon
$td.append($icon);
```

Comment: The total TD tag string is contained in a variable "cell", please advise me syntax for the suggested solution

Comment: Then you can use that string in the first line like `$td = $(cell)` to create a jQuery object from it that you can operate on.

Comment: Thanks Rudi, I did as follows, it works var $td = $(cell);
     var $icon = $td.find('i.fa:first');
     $icon.remove();

Answer (score 0):

another way with removeClass and addClass

```
$('.selectized').keyup(function(){
  if( $(this).val().length == 0 ){
    $(this).next().addClass('fa-exclamation-triangle')
    console.log($(this).val())
  }
  else{
    $(this).next().removeClass('fa-exclamation-triangle')
    console.log($(this).val())
  }
})
```

see this **[PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgedMg)**